# Two validation messages for the same data annotation regular expression in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, data-annotations

Can we show two validation messages for the same data annotation regular expression in MVC4.For example

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-z \$ \^]+$", ErrorMessage = "Name is not valid")]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

If two seperate messages need to be fired for Name for '$'  and '^' as they are not allowed. Is it possible through Data annotations or need to implement through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible. You need to use two regular expression with error message.

If you want to any thing like above you need to create your own [custom validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC) attribute and then in jQuery validate you need to [create a rule](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213138/An-Example-to-Use-jQuery-Validation-Plugin).